# EJB lifecycle ( request from client)

Tags: ejb

Hello everybody I am newbie for EJB component technology and i have to learn this in order to prepare my colloquium exam. I am not sure I can understand all details of the life cycle.

The life cycle includes these steps:

-The client request to EJB Container ( but how this request could be done ? Is the location of the request I mean that remote " outside of the EJB container" or local" inside of the EJB container" is important or not?)

-By depending on the request one bean instance is created in the pool and return to the client and after use from the client it returns again in the pool ( depending on the bean type(?).

I think this scenario appropriate for the stateless session bean but I am not sure. Because in stateful session bean scenario there is no pool.)

Advance thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "client" in this context just means "application code that will lookup/inject an EJB and call EJBs"; it is the opposite of "application code of the EJB itself" (which does not have a well-defined term; I've seen the term "EJB" overloaded for this meaning, or "service", etc.).  Local EJB vs remote EJB is not relevant in this context, even though "client" also has a well-defined meaning for remote.
2. Yes, pooling of session beans refers only to stateless session beans.  Stateful and singleton session beans do not have a pool.  Message-driven beans can also be pooled, but they are not directly invoked by a client per se, even though there can be a logical client; e.g., the one that send the JMS message.  (Entity beans can also be pooled, but they're not really relevant these days.)